# Syncing Podio and Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, podio

Is it possible to sync podio and dropbox so when I add data to my podio app it instantaneously updates dropbox. I know it is possible to add files from dropbox to podio but I am looking for a way to add podio files into dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with zapier
it will allow you to have 5 zaps for free but also the free version pull the changes every 15 minutes

Comment: Keep in mind that you have data on podio while you have files on dropbox so it is not the exactly something you can synchronize directly but zapier will let give you many options for synchronizing